# Call HTML file from outside component in component's HTML

Tags: html, angular

I want to call an HTML file `adverthome.html` in `advertisercomponent.html`, but can't do it:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a routerLink="../adverthome.html" class="nav-link">
        <span>Advertiser Home</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

My `adverthome.html` file is outside the component.

Comment: This adverthome is not a component?There is no adverthome.component.html?

Comment: yes adverthome is not a component its just a html file

Comment: Angular dosen't work like this. You have to create a component adverthome to be able to render it on your page. Why don't try this?

Comment: but i dont want an component i just want an html file.and i just want that data to display not any interaction with a user

Comment: can i do this  any another way, or its compalsary to have component?

Comment: This is the way angular works.It's a SPA so all your code (JS, HTML, CSS) is recovered with a single page stack. Further more, route between pages performed without invigorating the entire page.

Comment: can i do it with a href?

Comment: You can't render individual html files.Angular is a Single Page Appliaction.

Comment: I don't get what's your problem to use component

Comment: no i dont have any problem with using component i just want to know that ca we do it this way?

Comment: It's okay!If you read how spa working you will undrestand why!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a adverthome component. Add the code from the existing html on your adverthome.component.html. Now you can declare your adverthomeComponent on your routing module to use it with routing

You can't just render individual html files because Angular is a **SPA** so all your code (JS, HTML, CSS) is recovered with a single page stack. Further more, route between pages performed without invigorating the entire page

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a component, and specify `route` for it. You can't navigate like this, since it is not ordinar `<a>` element with `href` attribute. Rather it is just something like button which configured `Router` will handle `click`. It is not like `MPA` when you have multiple html pages. You have one page which will be updated by `Angular` using components and their logic (Tsc file), template (Html) and styling (css) (You can still have one component and declare HTML in `@Component` decorator)